# Find all matrices that belong to the stabilizer of a specific vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, group-actions

I am working on this problem and not sure about my solution so I would like some help:

> Find all matrices in the group $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb{F}_5)$ that are in the stabilizer of $\begin{pmatrix}
> 0\\
> 1
> \end{pmatrix}$ under left multiplication (The group $\operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb{F}_5)$ acts on $\begin{pmatrix}
> 0\\
> 1
> \end{pmatrix}$ by left multiplication), and determine the order (number of matrices) of the stabilizer.

My attempt:

Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}
$ with $a, b, c, d\in\Bbb{F}_5$. Because $M \cdot  \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}$, we have:
$$ a \times 0 + b \times 1 = 0,$$
and
$$c \times 0 + d \times 1 = 1,$$
and so $b = 0$ and $d = 1$. So the matrix has the form $M=\begin{pmatrix}
a &  0\\
c & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.

Because we have $24$ choices for the 1st column and 1 choice for then 2nd column, then the total number of matrices satisfying is 24.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is *almost* correct. Indeed such a matrix must be of the form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a &  0\\
c & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$
but you do *not* have $24$ choices for the first column; you need the matrix to be invertible. Equivalently, the first column must be linearly independent of the second column. How many choices does that leave?

Comment: Should that be 23, cause we should exclude (0 1) for (a c)?

Comment: @user545871 I would suggest to think geometrically; two vectors are linearly independent precisely when they are not parallel. So $\tbinom{a}{c}$ should not be on the line spanned by $\tbinom{0}{1}$.

Comment: @user545871 Alternatively you can look at the algebra; you need $ad-bc\neq0$, where $b=0$ and $d=1$, so...

Comment: So there are 4 choices for a since it has to be different than 0, and 5 choices for c so it's 20?

Comment: @user545871 Exactly. Geometrically, you can pick any vector in the plane that is not on a specified line. This leaves $5^2-5=20$ options.